# Android Studio add a custom button at the bottome middle to zxing capture

Tags: android-studio, zxing

I am using the lib bellow to make a qr scanner, I am calling the scan with a button. Everything is ok. I need to add a custom button at the bottom center of capture.

lib: `com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar`

And my code to call the scanner:

```
scannow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
        scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scanning...");
        scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
        scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);             scanIntegrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureActivityAnyOrientation.class);
        scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
        scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
});
```